# Layout for an ios app

Tags: swift, ipad, layout, constraints

I have some issues when i launch my swift application on ipad simulator. I have a home view witch displays 5 images. In my storyboard i have set for all of those constraints for height, width and also spacing. The problem is that when my app is running from ipad , the photo on the middle is situated over the other ones and the spacing is not as i expected.

What i want is a way i can make the same space value between images for each screen size and that the images will resize themselves in order to respect the initial view. Any piece of advice is more than welcome !^.^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove width and height constraints for your image views and add equal width and equal height constraints to them. Check out ["Auto Layout Tutorial"](http://www.raywenderlich.com/115444/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-2-constraints) section "Fixing the width" to see how to set equal width between views. I recommend you to read it whole :)

Answer (score 0):

Nikita is right.

I can add: often apps evolve, so you will add another image.. far better to pass to a CollectionView where every CollectionViewCell owns an image.

In this way:

1) you can decide layout very precisely (with constraints in InterfaceBuilder, or form code using NSCollectionViewFlowLayout delegate methods..)

2) You can manage rotation easily

3) You can scale for iPhone..